# Ruby on Rails API Deleted Account but Don't want lose all booking system

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, data-protection, gdprconsentform

There is a lot of changing with Data Protection and GDPR. I am not sure which is the right method for me to develop it.

The reason I was looking for advice because of the new Apply policy on account of deletion requirements extended https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=i71db0mv

We are using ROR API. and we have mobile App but we don’t have deletion account, only Deactivate Account cos we need to keep a record on booking history.

I was thinking something like that.

Create a new table “old_user_table” with old user_id, first name, second name, email, and booking slug.

It will allow keep all users who did previous booking. And deleted their user ID in the app. We need to keep all records for booking for audit purpose in the last 5-10 years in the app.

The user setup with this app, the user but never booking, then the user will not transfer to “old_user_table” cos the user booking nothing.

Does it make sense? Something like that? Or do you have a better alternative?

(FYI I’m not RoR Developer but I want to make sure I have better knowledge or better case before meeting with Ruby developers & IOS developer).

Comment: Why do you need to keep an audit log? Is this a requirement by law? Who will be requesting that data? Do you really need to be able to tell who exactly did a specific booking in the past? Or would it be enough to be able to tell that a specific booking was done by a deleted and therefore now anonymized user?

Comment: If you are required to keep this information then why even move it? Maybe just capture `deactivated_at` and creating a job to obfuscate records beyond your required retention period e.g. `deacivated_at > 10.years.ago` then set the PII to `"XXXXXXX"`

Comment: Ok, it’s make sense regarding on booking, there is money involved, and payment. If the user book and pay for it, it will show our balance in payment, then a few months later, user deleted their account, that mean booking is gone with payment, so once our balance will be change, and it will affect balance or our payment etc, I know we use stripe but it important to have check payment history.

Answer (score 2):

That approach won't be GDPR compliant since you are keeping [PII](https://www.techtarget.com/searchsecurity/definition/personally-identifiable-information-PII) in the old_ table.

If you want to keep the old bookings I would replace the user_id for some new random generated UUID that has no link with the real user, and then remove the user from the database.

Comment: That is not correct. It is absolutely fine to keep personal identifying information when you are required to keep those data because of other laws. Imagine your system sends money to users then you absolutely need to keep those data because you might be required to explain when and to who you sent money.

Comment: If that is the case that applies to the original post, it may make more sense to just have a boolean or a datetime field with the timestamp of the removal.